# Multithreading a Bash Script

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash

I'm finding it difficult to run this script multithreaded.

I cannot fix the script, I do not know what error I am making, as there are not many examples in the stack.

```
#!/bin/bash

function teste(){

    for i in $(seq 0 10); do

    CONNECT_TIMEOUT=1 # in seconds
    A="$1."
    B=$i
    IP_ADDRESS=$A$B
    PORT="${2}"

    set +e
    data=$(curl --head -vs -m ${CONNECT_TIMEOUT} http://${IP_ADDRESS}:${PORT} 2>&1) 
    exit_code="$?"
    data=$(echo -ne "${data}" | grep "Server: ") 
    set -e

    if [[ ${exit_code} -eq 0 ]]; then
    if [[ -n "${data}" ]]; then
    echo -ne "${IP_ADDRESS} - ${data}"
    else
    echo "${IP_ADDRESS} - Got empty data for server!"
    fi
    else
    echo "${IP_ADDRESS} - no server."
    fi

    done

}
function doexecute(){
set -e

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") ip_address_number port" 
exit 1
fi

threads=10;

threads=$(( $threads - 1))

for thread in `seq $threads`
do
teste ${1} &
done
}
doexecute
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the actual problem you have? Do you need to fix something in the script? You cannot multithread a bash script, you need to use jobs if you want to run multiple commands simultaneously.

Comment: I need to rotate the for this IPS sequence in multitrhead

Answer (score 0):

Your `doexecute` function expects 2 arguments, else it prints an error message and exits (not returns). So, when you call it without any argument it just exits the calling shell.